# Using Queues as global and working on its contents from main

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am getting errors about the template arguments not being valid and it is not seeing that I declared my queue variables as global.., i tried putting them inside the function (but thats not what I want because i want to deque from main) and does not work either.. Here are my errors and code

```
program.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
program.cpp:62:24: error: argument of type ‘bool (std::queue<std::basic_string<char> >::)()const’ does not match ‘bool’
program.cpp:62:24: error: in argument to unary !
program.cpp:68:23: error: argument of type ‘bool (std::queue<std::basic_string<char> >::)()const’ does not match ‘bool’
program.cpp:68:23: error: in argument to unary !






#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

#define SIZE 100

using namespace std;

  queue<string> bfFilesQueue;
  queue<string> bfDirsQueue;

static int display_info(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
             int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{

    //Check the type of Flag (i.e File or Directory)
    switch(tflag)
    {
        case FTW_D: 
        case FTW_F: 
                    bfFilesQueue.push(fpath);
                    break;

        case FTW_DP: 
                     bfDirsQueue.push(fpath);
                     break;
    }
    return 0; /* Continue */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s directory_name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1; 
    }  

    int flags = FTW_DEPTH | FTW_MOUNT | FTW_PHYS;


    if (nftw(argv[1], display_info, 20, 1) == -1)
    {
        perror("nftw");
        return 255;
    }
   printf("***************************\n");

   while(!bfFilesQueue.empty)
   {
       cout << bfFilesQueue.front() << " ";
        bfFilesQueue.pop();
   }

   while(!bfDirsQueue.empty)
   {
       cout << bfDirsQueue.front() << " ";
        bfDirsQueue.pop();
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: bfFilesQueue.empty() and not bfFilesQueue.empty. You're calling a method. Same for bfDirsQueue.

Comment: I just reverted your edit. Do not just edit away your question, even if it has been solved. This only confuses others who later come to this site and wonder what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while statements are attempting to check the function std::queue::empty() itself, and not the result of a call to the function. The type that appears in your error message is the type of the function.

As overcoder's comment says, adding parentheses will fix the code.